# Does Apache allow to authorize an HTTP request based on a result of a subrequest?

Tags: apache, authentication, authorization

I'm looking for an equivalent of [nginx http auth request module](https://github.com/PiotrSikora/ngx_http_auth_request_module) but for Apache.

For each incoming HTTP requests, the module sends a subrequests to authentication/authorization back-end. The auth request carries a path and all headers of the original request. Based on the result of the auth request, the original requests is allowed (HTTP code 200), denied (HTTP code 403) or login is requested (HTTP code 401). Such a generic mechanism allows to build really flexible authentication and authorization schemes.

Is something like this possible in Apache (likely with a help of some third party module)?

Comment: have you found a solution??

Answer (score 1):

This module does just that ... http://search.cpan.org/~chansen/Authen-Simple-HTTP-0.2/lib/Authen/Simple/HTTP.pm

# or as a mod_perl Authen handler

```
PerlModule Authen::Simple::Apache
PerlModule Authen::Simple::HTTP

PerlSetVar AuthenSimpleHTTP_url "http://www.host.com/protected"

<Location /protected>
  PerlAuthenHandler Authen::Simple::HTTP
  AuthType          Basic
  AuthName          "Protected Area"
  Require           valid-user
</Location>
```

Answer (score 1):

The closest built-in equivalent seems to be [mod_authnz_fcgi](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authnz_fcgi.html). This allows you to do authentication subrequests to an FCGI handler, using [mod_proxy_fcgi](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy_fcgi.html). It doesn't as directly allow you to pass on to another URL handler, but an FCGI handler could be configured to do that.

Answer (score 0):

[Apache2::AuthCookie](http://search.cpan.org/~mschout/Apache-AuthCookie-3.22/lib/Apache2/AuthCookie.pm) does something like this if you're willing to use mod_perl.

Comment: For every request ngnix makes a sub http request to a url and looks for 200 or non-200 response. If its 200 the original request goes through, else the errordocument fires.

authcookie presents actual content to the end user.

There are a number of mod_auth mechanisms that do similar subrequests like this dacs and such.